# How to Resize CALayer (AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer) to fit in UIView, wrapped for SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to understand how a `CALayer` (`AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer`, specifically) can adjust its scaling to fit within the bounds of a `UIView` I've added it to. I'm working on a project that uses a C++ library to write data into `CMSampleBuffer` and enqueue those to be displayed by a `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer`. I'm using SwiftUI to do the frontend code, so the UIView is being wrapped to allow for that.

The problem I'm having is that the `UIView` scales down to fit within the screen correctly, but the `CALayer` that is added to it does not scale to match the view, and therefore most of the video that's being played runs outside the bounds of the view and ends up being clipped by the iPhone screen.

My goal is to have the `CALayer` scale to fill whatever the bounds of the view its in are, so that I can shrink or enlarge the view and the video playing in the `CALayer` scales to match.

I'm creating the view with the following:

```swift
struct VideoPlayer: UIViewRepresentable {
    var player: AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer
    
    var view: some UIView {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1920, height: 1080))

        player.frame = view.bounds
        player.bounds = view.bounds
        player.videoGravity = .resizeAspect

        view.layer.addSublayer(player)
        return view
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {}
}
```

And setting it up with this code so that it regularly calls the library function to fill the buffers with new data:

```swift
struct VideoView: View {
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.015, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        let sampleLayer = AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer()
        let player = VideoPlayer(player: sampleLayer)

        return player.onReceive(timer) { _ in
            let buffer = retrieve_video_buffers()
            if buffer != nil {
                player.player.enqueue(buffer!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, to display the view in SwiftUI, I'm using the following.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VideoView()
                .aspectRatio(CGSize(width: 1920, height: 1080),
                             contentMode: ContentMode.fit)
        }
    }
}
```

To see where the clipping is happening, I added background colors to the `UIView` and `CALayer`. The `UIView` is green, and the `CALayer` is pink.

[iPhone Simulator in Portrait mode showing CALayer extending past View bounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKaRv.png)

[iPhone Simulator in Landscape mode showing CALayer extending past View bounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBJcT.png)

Any help at all is appreciated! I feel quite stuck being unable to figure this out.